# Talend Erreur : data import problem (postgres to postgres) under talend

Tags: postgresql, talend

I have five tables in postgres with the same column.

I have used talend in order to extract data from these tables and pass it into a single table in postgres too.

The source tables and the destination tables have the same name and number of columns.
Table source :
[image]

Destination table :

[image]

here are the tables under postgres, the destination table and the table under the name dubai_courts

[image]

I used Talend to do the ETL process but I got the following error:

[image]

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: delimited identifier of zero length on or near <<" ">>

Comment: Figure out the actual SQL statement run (PostgreSQL log file).

Comment: Could you show the query you are writing into your tDbinput ? and also edit the schema and a capture to your schema could be apprecieted ?  because probably there one column that have length = 0  thanks !